# Difference between walker class and basic php

Tags: menus, walker

I started to work with Walker class days ago and I still have this simple question:

When building sub-menus and drop-down menus, **what is the difference between using Walker class to build it, or simply using php** foreach loop with html tags and if statements?

As a beginner, I still see that Walker class is complicated for unconvincing reasons.

P.S: if you answer with 'walker is more dynamic', please explain it with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are building a theme just for your own website you could easily achieve with some PHP loops what the - indeed, more difficult to understand - [walker class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker/) achieves. After all, the class just walks through a tree-like structure and does nothing more. If you know exactly what you want your tree to look like, you can go at it directly with PHP.

Things become different when you are building something more generic, like a theme that might have child themes. Then you want flexibility for your users. For instance, take the [`walker_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) class which is itself already an extension of the walker class. The advantage is not so much in the html it generates by default. The difference is in the filters it incorporates, such as [`nav_menu_css_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class), which allows a user to change the classes attached to menu `<li>` items with a function in his child's `functions.php`. For example:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'wpse240664_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function wpse240664_nav_class($classes, $item){
     if(is_single() && $item->title == 'About Us'){
             $classes[] = 'highlight-this';
     }
     return $classes;
}
```

With this function the child theme adds a 'highlight-this' class to the menu item 'About Us' on single pages. The alternative would have been to edit the menu template file (probably `header.php`). Just to modify one menu item you would have to duplicate the whole `header.php` in your child theme. When the parent theme's `header.php` is updated you'll have to check your child copy for necessary changes. All this you avoid if you use the walker class. More difficult to implement, perhaps, but it saves time for other users of your code.

Comment: For a theme development career, do you suggest working with Walker?

Comment: Of course. When you want a carreer in something you should be familiar with all instruments that come with the trade,